# Update time of a big table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a question for performance for update on a big table that is around 8 to 10GBs of size.
I have a task where i'm supposed to detect distinct values from a table of mentioned size with about 4.3 million rows and insert them into some table. This part is not really a problem but it's the update that follows afterwards. So i need to update some column based on the id of the created rows in the table i did an import. A example of the query i'm executing is:

```
UPDATE billinglinesstagingaws as s
SET product_id = p.id
FROM product AS p
WHERE p.key=(s.data->'product'->>'sku')::varchar(75)||'-'||(s.data->'lineitem'->>'productcode')::varchar(75) and cloudplatform_id = 1
```

So as mentioned, the staging table size is around 4.3 million rows and 8-10Gb and as it can be seen from the query, it has a JSONB field and the product table has around 1500 rows.
This takes about 12 minutes, which i'm not really sure if it is ok, and i'm really wondering, what i can do to speed it up somehow. There aren't foreign key constraints, there is a unique constraint on two columns together. There are no indexes on the staging table.
I attached the query plan of the query, so any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The JOIN on the string contatenation will not allow any indexes to be used. The only thing the DBMS can do is to actually perform the string concatenation (for the target table) and do the compare. This is basically what happens once you violate 2NF.

Comment: An execution plan is better included as formatted next, not as a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too long for a comment.

Updating 4.3 million rows in a table is going to take some time.  Updates take time because the the ACID properties of databases require that *something* be committed to disk for each update -- typically log records.  And that doesn't count the time for reading the records, updating indexes, and other overhead.

So, about 17,000 updates per second isn't so bad.

There might be ways to speed up your query.  However, you describe these as new rows.  That makes me wonder if you can just insert the correct values when creating the table.   Can you lookup the appropriate value during the *insert*, rather than doing so afterwards in an `update`?

Comment: I don't have an option of adding the exact ids when creating the table. The problem i have is that i have 16 of similar updates in a row, so that adds to some time. The fact i thought about is that query written in this manner should lock the whole table (if i'm not mistaken) so that kills any amount of parallelism that i may achieve. If i would split that update query into maybe 20 smaller updates (or even higher) by ids in ranges that would update just a chunk of the table, then i may be able to run these updates in parallel which should give me a ok execution time. Does that make sense?

Comment: @СтефанЦолић . . . Splitting the update into separate chunks makes sense.  The update shouldn't be locking the entire table, it should be locking the row.  Your idea is fine, but databases also allow concurrent updates.